# Extract listening audio request url in bandcamp

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

Extract listening audio request url in bandcamp

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR4K8.png)

1. The song that I currently listening.
2. Inspect elements > Network
3. Media
4. Files
5. File Request Header

I need to get that files and request headers. Is there a any way to do it with python?
There have no href audio files into website.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the network traffic in a browser. Browsers don't run Python. Are you sure this is what you want to do? It's impossible.

Comment: @DanielDarabos Question updated. Described what I really want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ellhe-blaster I need to extract that audio urls. I read the code, but theres no embeded urls of those audios. After I watched inspect elements network tracffic. in media tab, I found audio streaming url. After I tried to find that url in webpage using python. But unfortunately couldnt found a way to do it.

Comment: What did you try so far?
Which is the error you get?
Please always provide a [mcve] and kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There's no general way to do this in Python. Modern web pages perform a lot of work in JavaScript. Without executing that JavaScript there's no universal way to figure out what content it would load.

This can often be done for specific web sites, though. You can use the debugging tools in your browser to understand the JavaScript code and how it gets the URL of the audio content. For popular sites you can also find existing scrapers. (E.g. https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor or https://github.com/masterT/bandcamp-scraper for Bandcamp.)